# Need Help in Android Notifications

Tags: android, notifications

I'm developing an app where 
I had to show notification , 
I am showing it sucessfully but however I want
when user click on notification it should dial a mobile number ...

MyNotify.java

```
    package com.premiumtechhelp.net;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.TextView;





        public class Mynotify extends Activity {

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                TextView txt = new TextView(this);

                txt.setText("Some text here");
                setContentView(txt);
            }
        }
```

MainActivity.java

```
private static final int NOTIFY_ME_ID = 1337;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
                "Hello Notifi", System.currentTimeMillis());
        PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
                Mynotify.class), 0);
        note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Hello text",
                "mobile number 9906012345", i);
        mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, note);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the number as extra to the intent where you create the notification:

```
final String number = "1234567890";
final NotificationManager mgr = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(
                                                   Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification note = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Hello Notifi",
                                     System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Mynotify.class);
intent.putExtra("number", number);
PendingIntent i = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
nte.setLatestEventInfo(this, "Hello text", "mobile number " + number, i);
mgr.notify(NOTIFY_ME_ID, note);
```

Than you can grep it in your activity with:

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView txt = new TextView(this);
    String number = getIntent().getStringExtra("number");
    txt.setText("Some text here " + number);
    setContentView(txt);
}
```

Comment: sorry not getting you

Comment: i actually need it when user click on notification

Comment: If I understood the question correctly you know a number when you create a notification, when you receive the notification you don't know the number. So the solution is to store the number in the (Pending)Intent when you know the number. If the notification is clicked the (Pending)Intent is fired with the (unknown) number. Then you just need to read the number in your activity from the intent. That store and read lines are in my answer above.

Comment: i actually show you these two classes i dont know where to place this snippet of code , the first one and the second one

Comment: I extended the example. Hopfully you get it now.

Comment: You tried you best how ever it wasn't what i want , actually i want to make a call when user click on notification

Comment: Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);     callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:18009011930"));
startActivity(callIntent);

Comment: Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);     callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:18009011930"));
startActivity(callIntent);